Why is Election Day still the most common day to vote with early voting available?
In the US, Election Day is always on a Tuesday where most people have to work. It can be super crowded with long lines, and if something happens on that day preventing you from voting you can't vote the day after.
With early voting available in most states, it should be treated as the last day you can vote rather than the day you should vote. There doesn't seem to be an upside over voting whenever it is convenient.
Yet despite early voting being available in most states, half the population still choose to vote then.
Why is this so?

Absent any specific poll, we can only guess. I will refrain to VtC as "Questions asking for the internal motivations of people, [...]" because perhaps such a poll exists. Other than that, it is speculation: tradition, undecided people wanting to get more information, procrastination, lack of faith in the security of deposited ballots...

Is there a list of states that do not allow early voting?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Alabama, Mississippi and New Hampshire

This article seems to say that in parts of Pennsylvania it is the early in-person voting that has the long lines, not election day voting.

Something to remember when it comes to early voting not all states allow it and some of the ones that allow it don't make it easy to do. Not to mention depending on where you live the time to vote can easily range from minutes with no wait at all to a short and reasonable wait of 30 minutes or less.

In 2020, the average wait time to vote was over 11.6 minutes in 21 states, under in 29 states and DC. So your premise of long lines is wrong. I personally, in MA, have never been more than 3rd in line at my precinct, where I've been voting for over 30 years.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution Here is an article that talks about early and absentee voting https://www.cbsnews.com/news/map-early-voting-mail-ballot-states/

@Barmar That just shows you how the averages can remove the outliers from the picture as there are areas in the country that people had to wait 4+ hours to vote due to the small number of polling locations compared to the voting population. https://www.npr.org/2020/10/17/924527679/why-do-nonwhite-georgia-voters-have-to-wait-in-line-for-hours-too-few-polling-pl

Probably related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/89620/is-there-a-sizeable-difference-in-the-number-of-polling-locations-opened-for-ear/89621#89621

This is a "Why doesn't everyone else feel like I do?" type of question.


Why is election Day still the most common day to vote?

Rhetorical question: Is it? In many states in this election over half of the likely voters have already voted either by absentee mail-in voting or by in-person early voting. We'll see how big the in-person election day voting is in the 2024 election.
That said, there are several reasons people don't use early voting in some form:

FOMO (In this case, not Fear Of Missing Out but rather Fear Of Missing October surprises). Some people intentionally wait until the last minute just in case something that might change their vote pops up.
Inertia. Waiting until election day was the only choice for most people until fairly recently. Several states still restrict who can vote by mail, and early in-person voting is a fairly recent phenomenon. Even though most states now allow some form of early voting, that voting on election day was and is what one does remains to be the rule to some.
The social experience. If the lines on election day aren't onerously long, they can be a pleasant social experience. Those who vote on election day get the opportunity say hi to their neighbors, say hi to the kids they coached in a youth sport program who are now voting, say hi to all kinds of people. Mail-in voting definitely is not a social experience, not at all. Early in-person voting can also be a bit sterile. You walk in, wait behind one or two people, cast your vote, and walk out.
COVID-19. Many voters did vote early in the 2020 election due to the nastiness of covid, and they didn't like it. Some people equate early voting with nasty tasting medicine. The proportion of early voters in the 2022 election was down compared to the 2020 election.


FOMO as you described can be important for everyone who is not a diehard supporter of one side or another, voting for them no matter what. Imagine I'm reluctantly preferring one candidate over the other, vote early, and then something big happens before the final election day, and I can no longer change my vote. Maybe a big scandal where I realize the one I voted for is much worse than I thought, or a new war breaks out and the candidate I did not vote for announces a policy I prefer much more than what the other one announced, etc.

I would like to suggest: force of habit? This was the first year I ever voted early. I always voted on Election Day because... you vote on Election Day.

@JoeB That's exactly what I meant by "inertia".

I don't know just how universal they are (although they're very common in my experience), but it might be worth mentioning the "I Voted" stickers as part of the social experience.

@Bobson Those stickers are also available at early in-person voting.

@Bobson My wife also received an "I Voted" sticker in the letter with her mail-in ballot this year. so whether or not either of us make it to the polls this year, we will still have a sticker.

On election day every polling place is open, staffed, with hours all day, and has a dozen little stations set up (a small card table with 3 high sides and a felt-tip pen tied to a string). I can go to the nearby school where I always go and be done in 1/2-hour at most. I heard some stuff about early voting but didn't feel a need to pay attention.
Looking now, the early voting hours in my state are only 10am-4pm, Mon-Fri. The website also says you're filling out an absentee ballot. I was by one coincidentally last week -- a library a few miles away which seems to be my nearest. There was a long line, outside in the cold (my normal polling place has enough room to wait inside), which seemed to be moving very slowly.

At least speaking from my experience in Tennessee, I've voted early something like 2 or 3 times in my life and those were also the only times I've ever waited in a line of more than 5 minutes to vote. Most often, there is no line at all at the multiple precincts where I've voted over the two decades I've been voting on election day. I rarely spend more than 10 minutes in the building on election day, usually more like 5, including the time to verify ID and actually vote.
So, to explicitly answer the question, for a lot of us the answer is "because it's significantly faster."
Also, at least in my state, employers are required by law to allow employees to be absent to vote for up to 3 hours on election day if they're otherwise scheduled to work a shift that does not either start 3 or more hours after polls open or end 3 or more hours before they close. This absence is required to paid. No such requirement exists for early voting. While not every state has such a statute, it appears that most of them have some requirements for employers to allow leave on election day. (link is PDF)
For early voting, there is one site in the whole county that is open. On election day, every precinct is open, of which there are at least dozens in the county. Your assigned voting precinct also tends to be relatively close to where you live, whereas the site open for early voting is farther away.
Remember that most voting precincts are not typically dedicated buildings for that purpose. It would be ridiculously expensive for the local election commissions to maintain dozens of properties around their city or county vs. just one at their headquarters, which is also often a shared building with other city/county offices. So, while it's relatively easy for them to have a spot at their headquarters building open for a few weeks for voting, blocking off spaces for weeks at the dozens of schools, community centers, etc. where all of the local precincts are for voting would be much more difficult and/or expensive. Plus, they would then need poll workers at each of those places for weeks on end vs. just one day, which is also much more difficult and/or expensive (difficult to find volunteers for that long, expensive if you pay people.)
As a result of the cost of operating polling places for extended durations vs. only one day, it is more efficient to have early voting available with enough capacity for people who actually need it (e.g. due to being unavailable on election day, such as for travel, important events, etc.,) but for most others to vote on election day.


Even with early voting, there's a tremendous ramp-up in things like advertising and media coverage that reaches its peak on election day itself. At some point that ramp-up pierces the bubbles of some voters, who suddenly realize they need to vote. This is why run-off elections have lower voter turnout, because they don't receive the same coverage as the main election.

Some people still fear absentee or drop-box balloting. While it's rare, sometimes people do attempt to destroy the ballots of others.

Fires were set at three ballot boxes in the area in the past three weeks. An “incendiary device” found attached to the side of a ballot drop box in Portland, early Monday damaged ballots, but most were unaffected because of fire suppressant installed in the ballot box. Another fire was set at a ballot box in Vancouver, Washington, the same day.

While most ballots were saved, it's possible some votes were destroyed

Elections staff will mail another 143 replacement ballots to voters Thursday, officials said on X. Workers were unable to identify six of the damaged ballots. Other ballots may have been completely burned to ash, and therefore, unidentifiable, Clark County officials said in a news release Wednesday.


Early and absentee voting may require more work overall. Early voting is typically more limited in polling places, with more polling places open on election day itself. Absentee ballots may require filling out paperwork weeks or months in advance and then following instructions accurately

But since Pennsylvania implemented its no-excuse mail voting law, Act 77, in 2020, thousands of ballots have been rejected because of procedural errors by voters, such as missing dates and signatures. Courts have gone back and forth on which errors should cause a ballot to be rejected. So far, the divided legislature hasn’t successfully stepped in to clarify the rules.




Personal anecdote in support of (3): I’ve twice missed the mail-in application deadline. Last time, I looked at early voting and it was further away and such, while my day-of polling place was like 5 mins away. And since the the lines in the middle of the day were nonexistent, I was going to do that again this year, except something came up such that I would be out of state on voting day (so I opted to vote early). Have also voted by mail and making sure I didn’t screw up was a source of stress.

Convenience and #3.  Sure, there are ways to do mail in ballots or advance voting, but with short line ups and relatively clear options, the lazy way out for many is to "just walk to the nearest voting booths".

Universal Law of Procrastination
In addition to the other election-specific answers, I'll point out that some of this comes down to human psychology and has nothing to do with elections in particular. Election Day is a deadline, the last possible day to vote. It is well understood anecdotally and scientifically that people tend to procrastinate - when given a window of time to complete some task, it's common to see the rate of task completion skyrocket as the deadline approaches  (examples here and here).
As one example, the most common time for Americans to submit their tax returns is the week they are due - this is true even though submissions are open for months, and most filers would enjoy a direct financial benefit by filing earlier. Basically, it doesn't matter how long you've seen the deadline coming or how long you've had to do it, or even if it will be better for you to do it earlier, people just tend to not do things earlier than they need to.
If you give many people 10 days to do anything, a large number of them will wait until the 10th day to do it. If Election Day were the first day of a days-long voting period instead of the last, I would expect it to be somewhat less popular. There are of course election-related reasons for why Election Day might be especially popular, but I'd expect a similar effect to be observed with almost any deadline-oriented task - it's fairly typical for things to get done at the deadline and no sooner, whether it's filing taxes or voting for president or turning in your homework.

Good point. For what it's worth, to put some numbers to this, for this year, the IRS had received 119.6 million returns by April 12 and received another 19.5 million by April 19, so around 14% of returns came within the week where tax day fell. Not as high as election day voting, but still a lot.

I would be interested to see how that distribution looks for people who do their own taxes, as opposed to those done by a professional.

@Jac Looking at the stats, there is a bias toward self-filers procrastinating more. About 15% of returns are sent back the week of Tax Day, which includes nearly 20% of self-filed returns, but only about 10% of returns filed by professionals. Procrastinating is especially easy if you don't need to involve anyone else.

People have already given a number of logistic factors that make it easier to vote on election day in some states. To analyze the psychology of this question we can look at states where the entire electorate votes by mail - which removes all questions about convenience, access, social experience, difference in format, and trust in the method.
In Washington, you receive a ballot by mail about three weeks before the election, and you vote by dropping off your ballot either at a dedicated return box or in a normal mail pickup[1]. The majority of ballots are returned before election day, but a significant percentage (maybe 1/3, it varies) are still not returned until the day of, leading to actual lines of people building up for the 8pm deadline at the drop boxes. (https://www.capitolhillseattle.com/2018/11/chs-pics-a-steady-flow-of-democracy-fills-broadways-ballot-drop-box-on-election-day/)
https://komonews.com/news/local/washington-voter-turnout-ballots-cast-box-decision-election-candidate-kamala-harris-donald-trump-voting-mail-usps
So people wait not just until the last day, but the last moment to vote. It seems like run of the mill procrastination.
[1] It is possible to vote in person if you miss the mail registration deadline, need an accessible ballot, lose your ballot and don't get a replacement one in time, etc. but less than 1% of votes are returned this way https://www.sos.wa.gov/elections/data-research/election-data-and-maps/ballot-return-statistics

Ugh. It's a good thing Washington is one of the last states anyway and its outcome in national elections is usually a foregone conclusion. A bunch of people dropping off mail-in ballots at the last-minute means, not only that you can't start counting those until after polls are already closed, but that you don't even know how many votes were cast until at least hours later. That sounds atrocious. Thank goodness the swing states don't do that or we wouldn't know outcomes for days or more.

@reirab "...you can't start counting those until after polls are already closed..." That's as it's supposed to be, right? First voting, then counting. And in other countries, the mail-in ballots are counted alongside the normal ballots and final results are typically obtained within a day. I mean the total number of votes to count is roughly the same, regardless of how you vote. So I don't see where the additional effort comes from and I guess that some US states must do something severely wrong there, maybe under-staffing their vote counting force?

I can answer with reasons that apply to me personally and are consistent with reasons I've heard from others.

Election day at my polling place is never crowded and never has long lines at the time I go to vote. It's a high turnout area, but we have a ton of election support from our clerk and there are a ton of polling locations and voting moves swiftly at all of them. There can be a bit of a rush early and end of day, mirroring the typical work schedule, but that's predictable and easily (for me) avoidable.

In-person early voting in my area is at few locations. This year, there has been a lot of early voting, which has resulted in long lines at some of those locations. It's also been hard to predict; they use different machinery for early voting and occasionally things happen like a machine is down and the line is longer than usual.

A slight paranoia about mail-in or drop box absentee voting. There have been a couple cases of drop box arson in the country. There have been silly attempts by one political party to invalidate votes cast this way through the courts. There are some additional hoops where mistakes feel more likely to happen that could invalidate a ballot (with signatures, witnessing, etc). Even if it's extremely unlikely to affect my ballot, given (1) it seems like an unnecessary risk to take, even if it's small.

The circumstances that would prevent me from physically voting on election day are extremely unlikely to happen. In previous years, I've used absentee voting when it seemed more appropriate, like during the peak of the COVID pandemic, but I haven't missed an election I was eligible for. So, even though I might encourage others to use early voting, I don't find the reasons I would use to convince them all that convincing for myself.

Early voting where I live uses a slightly different system. Ultimately the results are the same, but it's an electronic machine that creates a printout rather than pen-on-paper. I kind of like filling in my own bubbles. Maybe I have a pathological fondness for the "scantron" sheets I used to get to use for multiple-choice exams in school.

I like the election day experience. It feels ceremonial to me. I walk to my polling place, I vote, I get my sticker.



The OSCE Office for Democratic Institutions and Human Rights has published a paper Alternative voting methods and arrangements. It discusses best practices to follow when offering (among other methods) early voting. Some of them can be taken as caveats voters themselves may have against voting before election day. The most serious reason voters may be reluctant is probably because they think information relevant to their decision may only become available on election day.

If early voting begins far in advance of election day, it may negatively impact the ability of early voters to make a fully informed choice. An early voter’s opinion could change, with no recourse.

Another aspect they mention concerns voter education about the availability:

...research is
divided on whether early voting significantly increases
voter turnout or just shifts when likely voters cast their
ballots. Voters that are less likely to cast a ballot are
often the same voters who are the least likely to be
aware of alternative voting methods, such as early
voting. As such, targeted voter education campaigns
that also consider language needs and literacy, are
often required to achieve stated goals.


I think you misunderstood the question. It's not about whether we should have early voting, but about why more people aren't taking advantage of it where it exists (which is most states).

@Barmar I have shortened and rewritten the answer. I still think the paper offers some insight into why early voting may have less positive effects than anticipated.

This seems to answer the question on why early voting should be limited to how early it can happen instead of why people choose not to early vote.

At least to some, any modification to traditions could be considered unwelcome.  Election Day stirs up patriotic feelings & the storied history of the US, while early voting days don't carry the same weight.  Essentially, they might ask themselves whether the Founders intended for early voting to alleviate all the possible excuses for missing the ballot box on the day set aside for it.  I'm certainly not aware of how many precincts were available in the days of old G.W., but I can imagine that conditions were somewhat less amenable to the entire experience, so that might figure into the calculation.

I wouldn't care much about Founding Father's views on this or that but voting indeed feels a bit like a collectively shared experience. Some kind of coming together of the public and deciding where it's going to be going to. Doing it on the same day has advantages. But I also may overestimating the amount of community-feeling there is actually inside. Or that people really come together at such occasions. Maybe they don't really.

If you look at history at times voting was done by party and not candidates like we do today. Keeping it the same as the founding fathers doesn’t seem correct.
