Is there a sizeable difference in the number of polling locations opened for early in-person voting vs election day in the US (for 2024)?
According to one expert:

With Election Day voting you likely have a polling site that is much closer to you.

I've done a few minutes of googling trying to find some data to confirm this, but came up empty. So, is it true? Are there any numbers to back this up?

I found a report here that says that many polling sites have been closed over the years, but it doesn't seem to distinguish early voting ones.

For comparison on NZ's 2023 election: "There will be more than 800 voting places open before election day and more than 2,300 voting places on election day."

This obviously varies by state and precinct.
But in my City (pop. ~185k), there are 2 locations for early in-person voting, and on election day, 34 locations.
Note that many of the election day locations are public schools. They can deal with the extra traffic for the one election day, but don't want that traffic every day for a month or so.

Out of interest: do you know how many of the population are registered voters?

@ccprog - Just looked it up. As of May 31 2024, 124,705 Registered Voters.

So an average of 3,700 potential voters per location on election day, and 62,000 per location for early voting, but stretched over multiple weeks. That sounds (roughly) like a rational distribution of resources.

This is also true in Virginia: near me the number of Election Day polling locations is at least four times greater than the number of early voting locations. Public schools are used here, too, and only on Election Day.

@ToddWilcox - My example above is also Virginia...;)

Making election day a non-school day would make this extra traffic trivial, by the way.

Dumb question: they use schools as polling locations on a regular school day? So the election stuff happens in parallel to all the school kids running around? In my home country schools are also popular polling locations but there are used precisely because on election day (= Sunday) the school is empty and hence the space is free to be used.

At my local polling place, it is an elementary school. Little kids. Voting happens in the gym. Walk in the front door, take an immediate right, into the gym. Cast the ballot, then out the side door. Its all marked off so there is little or no chance of going the wrong way.

@quarague my community changed all polling locations a couple of years ago to move away from schools to churches and community buildings, which are minimally utilized during the week. Early voting here all takes place at the city municipal center (one location), then on election day we have nine locations open.

@WPNSGuy My polling place is similar, the gym entrance is a 20-foot walk from the building entrance. In my town there are 32K registered voters (in 2022), 21 precincts, 9 voting locations on election day (8 elementary schools, 1 middle school, and town hall). Early voting can be done at town hall, 3 drop boxes, or by mail.

@quarague we just closed the elementary schools for tomorrow to avoid issues with parking and security

In my area (Montgomery County, MD, but at least some other local jurisdictions do the same thing) election day is a school holiday for all the public schools. Can't just close elementary schools (which are most of the polling places) because there is an incredibly complex busing network involving K through 12, special ed, etc. - so all the schools have the same holiday schedule.
